# Distributing Swift Framework with dependencies; Multiple versions of dependent library

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I have a set of swift code which I need to package into a framework and distribute to third parties, so they can bundle it into their iOS applications.
My code depends on RxSwift.

If one of the third party applications also depends on RxSwift, and their version is not the same as my version, what happens here?

A) How do I create a swift framework that depends on another swift framework

B) What happens if there's another copy of said swift framework bundled in the app with a different version.

C) Are there any other options I have? I'm quite happy to compile the RxSwift source code into my framework if that helps